How can I convert Radiance HDR or OpenEXR file to HEIF, preserving HDR?
I have an .hdr file. I can open it on my MacBook Pro (M2) in Preview or Photos and it's displayed correctly. I got this file from Affinity Photo, by using "HDR Stack" function. I then used "Export" function with .hdr format, but I also have an option of using OpenEXR format and it's also displayed correctly on Mac.
Now, I'd like to post this photo on Instagram. I'd like to preserve the HDR information. So far from my experiments I've found that:

iOS 18 will not display hdr files at all
iOS 18 will display OpenEXR files, but it's buggy: when zooming in, parts of the image flicker and switch back and forth between HDR and SDR-clamped versions. Instagram can open the photo itself, but it's not displayed correctly: it's clamped to SDR and exposure is overblown.
Export via Photos app on Mac produces a result that looks okay visually without overblown regions, but again it loses HDR information - so it just looks like low-contrast SDR clamped version

However, both iOS and Instagram are capable of correctly displaying HEIF images that contain HDR data.
I've tried using ImageMagick to convert .hdr to .heif, but unfortunately the output file doesn't preserve HDR, and contains overblown regions.
Is there software that is capable of creating proper HEIC with HDR, given .hdr or .exr?

How much highlights do you expect to be preserved? OpenEXR has almost infinite headroom but HEIF is only a 10-bit format. Somehow you'll need to master the images to have the correct exposure for what you need, to sure if that can be automated.

I wasn't able to find a tool other than Photoshop that would enable this conversion, so I wrote a (quick and dirty) program that converts Radiance HDR files to HEIC, preserving HDR highlights. I've tested it with a few photos and the results were displayed correctly on Mac, iOS, and in Instagram. However, it contains a number of hacks so I wouldn't expect it to perform correctly 100% of the time. The code is here:
https://gist.github.com/vlad-ivanov-name/9dd7298b9e6c55d865dcd6cf76ce483b

I was able to convert an OpenEXR file containing an HDR picture into an AVIF file with Rec.2020 profile and retain highlights, using PhotoShop (2024, v25.9.0) as follows:

Open the image in PhotoShop. It will load as a 32-bit image.
Open the Camera RAW filter, and adjust exposure as desired. Make sure it's in HDR mode.
In the Camera RAW filter, use the "Convert and save image" button on the top right toolbar (third from the right).
Select your desired export format, which for Instagram I believe is AVIF (according to this post)
Use the HDR Output option and select the Rec.2020 color space if it's not preselected
Save the image from within the Camera RAW filter.

I started experimenting with converting my Canon RAW images using Adobe Camera  RAW as soon as it became experimental. I stored them as OpenEXR because that's what I could demonstrate on my 2021 16" M1 MacBook Pro. Now that the feature has become mainstream I'm just using Lightroom and exporting to JPEG XL or JPEG with gain maps.
I don't use Instagram so I can't test it myself.

Thank you! While I don't have Photoshop, on the website you linked I found some HDR AVIF files and I can confirm they're displayed correctly by MacOS, iOS, and Instagram on iOS. So I guess this is one way to do it, although it's a shame it requires Photoshop.
